# Can't assign route to a popup dialog in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to assign a route to a custom popup that I've made using dialog component in vue.js, but I'm having a little trouble making it work. I've messed around a lot and honestly I'm quite confused on how to make this work. This is my route's file :

```
routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "landing",
      component: LandingView,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/register",
          component: RegistrationForm,
        },
      ],
    },
```

I have a landing page, inside that landing page, I'm using that RegistrationForm component, which is wrapped inside a custom Dialog component that I've made, which looks like this:

```
    <teleport to="body">
      <dialog-modal v-if="isOpenRegister" @close="isOpenRegister = false">
        <RegistrationForm
          @open-login="(isOpenRegister = false), (isOpenLogin = true)"
          @close-dialog="isOpenRegister = false"
        />
      </dialog-modal>
    </teleport>
```

I just want to assign a route to this popup window when the user clicks on it. So instead of having no route right now, as it is just http://localhost:5173, I want it to be http://localhost:5173/register, when the user clicks on the register button and the popup is activated. I'm sorry if this is a confusing question, tried my best explaining it,thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should handle redirecting inside some method, for example:

```
<teleport to="body">
  <dialog-modal v-if="isOpenRegister" @close="isOpenRegister = false">
    <RegistrationForm
      @open-login="openRegister"
      @close-dialog="isOpenRegister = false"
    />
  </dialog-modal>
</teleport>

<script>
 methods: {
   openRegister() {
     this.$router.push({ path: '/register' })
     // other method logic
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: that works only on button click, If i type in localhost/register in the browser, I still want the popup to open

Comment: It this case you also need watcher on route params, and in case of path equal to '/register' you should run the same logic as in method openRegister. Your modal is opening only in case of isOpenRegister, so you shoud change this property when url is changed manually